# How to detect CSS is turned off with PHP?

Tags: php, css

Say a user visits your site on an old blackberry with stylesheets off (and probably javascript off as well). How would you go about detecting if a browser was applying stylesheets or not?

Comment: I wouldn't. The markup would be good enough to stand alone. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you could probably do would be to find out what the browser is and from that, see what it's capable of.

I suggest you start looking at `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` but you can go quite a bit deeper with [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php).

Either way, as long as your markup makes sense (eg you use headers, hrs, paragraphs, em and strong, etc instead of meaningless CSS classes) a css-less browser should be able to render your content sensibly.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to detect that from the php's side.